What does "go" mean in "go off trade"?
I was watching a podcast "Fighter And The Kid" and one of the guests was joking about him having a cult. During the funny play-acted conversation in which he is trying to convince the other two to join it, he is asked about money and materialism in the cult and he answers that they don't like money and that he wished they could...
"...abolish all the money and go off trade*"
does "go" here mean:

to be or continue to be in a specified state or condition: to go in rags; to go in poverty.(Collins English Dictionary)

continue in operation or existence.
"the committee was kept going even when its existence could no longer be justified"(Oxford Languages Dictionary)



It's totally unclear, and probably not worth worrying about. It might be more clear if you could quote the full sentence and surrounding ones instead of summarizing them. Possibilities include "go off" = abandon, as a train "going off" the rails, meaning he wishes to depart from "trade" as in commerce; OR "go off trade" meaning proceed (go) in a way based upon (off [of]) trade i.e. a barter system without currency.

@AndyBonner It's definitely the latter. He says that  "we'd love to abolish all the money and go off trade". Is any of the definitions I provided appropriate for this context?

#2 doesn't really make sense; #1 is fine. Probably the more important is to understand this use of "off"; the best entry I can find is preposition #11 here: "from or by such means or use of: living off his parents / living off an inheritance"

@Andy Bonner I knew this usage of "off". Actually, I recalled this sample sentence (or maybe it's a clause, I'm not sure) in my head, before writing this post when I was thinking about its meaning (You might also say "go off of only bread and water for a week" I guess). The usage of "go" seemed enigmatic though. I though it might mean "to prosper" but I wasn't able to find anything to confirm it.

I would mentally replace it with "proceed"

@AndyBonner But this would suggest the #2 definition which you rejected. Proceed means "to carry on or continue any action or process."

#2 as you posted it is about the continued "survival" of the subject, not the action, as in "the committee was kept going." It would not pair well with "off of [noun]." Ironically, it would do ok with "on"; sometimes when low on gas in the car we say we're "running on fumes." Come to think of it, "on" can also often be substituted for "off" in the "from or by such means or use of" sense: He lives off bread and water, he lives on bread and water!

When the Brits say go off, they mean stop. Go off booze. Stop drinking. Go off trade means: stop trading.

@Lambie Worthwhile, but a bit of reluctant googling shows that in this case it's a standup comedian and UFC fighter bro-ing it up in LA. Not sure, as communication, that it's worth the time we've given it here...

In this context, to "go off" something means to rely on it. For example, if someone said "I'm not sure, I'm going off instinct" that would mean they were relying on their instinct to make a decision.
In your example it is referring to abolishing money and relying on a system of trade or bartering to make society function.
It is an odd phrase, because "go on" can sometimes mean the same thing.

The statement is a bit vague, but a good paraphrase would be "abolish all the money and proceed on a basis of a barter system."
Of the two definitions of "go" that you give, the first fits well: he proposes that we "be ... in a specified state or condition." Perhaps a better one would be Merriam-Webster's 3a: "to take a certain course or follow a certain procedure."
The second definition given, "continue in operation or existence," is not so much about what we do or how we do it, as about we ourselves surviving, as its example shows ("the committee kept going"). While that idea is not very distant from the idea of an economy, it's not the speaker's main point. A good example of this usage is when Celine Dion sings that "my heart will go on": it will persist, endure, and, well, continue in operation or existence. The speaker in the podcast is talking more about "proceeding" than existing.

Isn't the structure of the expression under discussion pretty much the same as go off-piste which, at least in the UK, is an idiom: mainly UK humorous to do something different to what is normal or expected: The presenter went off-piste from the script, with hilarious consequences.

@MichaelHarvey Mmm I wouldn't say so; if I've learned anything from poring over entries for "off" today it's that it has a multitude of shades of usage. But "off-piste" or Am equivalent "off-script" seem just to be the simple "away from" positional sense, albeit figurative (on course, off course; on the ski slop, off the ski slope; on the script, off the script).

Yes, I did that indispensable thing (read the damn question properly).

I don't disagree with the end results of the other answers, just with how to get there.
The verb "go" has the common meaning "proceed" or "act" but the preposition off there has one of its more unusual meanings, "in accordance with, adhering to or following", and what is being followed are the dictates of something.

Oh, for crying out loud. Son, when the time is right, just go off your heart,” Mike said. “Be with whoever makes you happy in life—even if it's Monica.
The Murdered Out by Ty Humburd (2018)

Proceed in accordance with what your heart is telling you to do.

That desk doesn't look quite right. Where do your legs go?
--Well, I went off the assembly instructions.

I adhered to, I followed ... the instructions.

Going off those clues, there's no way Colonel Mustard could have been the murderer.

In accordance with those clues, we must conclude that Colonel Mustard was not the murderer.
So, to "go off trade" would be to "proceed" according to the practice of trading or barter.
We often use the preposition from to have that same meaning, and it is in that case synonymous with off in this sense.
Ultimately there is a figurative locative sense to the preposition that yields that meaning.  Proceeding from those facts, going off those facts ...
